# How can I load .msg file into GreenMail mailbox

Tags: testing, jakarta-mail, greenmail

I'd like to load .msg bounce mail sample to GreenMail mock mailbox for testing. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure I'd just share my findings.

Firstly this is beyond GreenMail library scope. You could use JavaMail library to load a message sample, preferably an .eml file and store them in the dummy mailbox created using GreenMail.

Secondly, .msg is an Outlook message file, a proprietary of Microsoft. And as I post this, currently there are no free Java library that can successfully load and convert .msg file into raw message format, .eml which what JavaMail can work on.